# Prove that $ad-bc=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $r$ a irrational number. Let $a,b,c,d$ rational numbers such that $\dfrac{ar+b}{cr+d} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Prove that $ad-bc=0$.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's rational, there exists some $p,q\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\frac{ar+b}{cr+d}=\frac pq$. So, $qar+qb=pcr+pd$. So, $r(qa-pc)=pd-qb$. Hence, $qa-pc=0$, so $qb=pd$.

So, if $a=0$, $c=0$, we are done. If $a\neq0$, $c\neq0$, so $q=\frac{pc}a$, and $pcb=pad$. Since $a\neq0$, $ar+b\neq0$, so $p\neq0$. So, $cb=ad$.

Answer (score 6):

If $\dfrac{ar+b}{cr+d} = q \in \mathbb{Q}$, then what is $r$?

Comment: What is so bad about this answer?  This is what the OP should have started with.  After all the OP asked for a hint.

Comment: I agree, why is it being downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

Call the fraction $q$ so $0=ar+b-q(cr+d)=(a-qc)r+b-qd$. Since $0\in\Bbb Q$, $a-qc=0$ and $b-qd=0$, so $ad-bc=qcd-qdc=0$.